# How to run the command bracketOrder in ib_insync

Tags: python-3.x, interactive, algorithmic-trading, interactive-brokers, ib-insync

In the following code snippet I try to create one action that consists of both Stop loss and Take profit

```
from ib_insync import *


util.startLoop()
ib = IB()
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, clientId=1)

contract = Future(symbol='ES', lastTradeDateOrContractMonth='202309', exchange='CME')

order = ib.placeOrder(contract, MarketOrder('BUY', 1))
ib.sleep(1)

ticker = ib.reqMktData(contract, genericTickList='', snapshot=True) # Request real-time market data
ib.sleep(1) # Wait for the ticker to receive data

current_price = ticker.marketPrice()

takeProfitPrice = current_price + 10 # Replace with your desired take profit price
stopLossPrice = current_price - 10 # Replace with your desired stop loss price

takeProfitOrder = LimitOrder('SELL', 1, takeProfitPrice)
stopLossOrder = StopOrder('SELL', 1, stopLossPrice)

ib.sleep(1)

bracket = ib.bracketOrder('SELL', 1, takeProfitPrice+100, stopLossPrice+100, stopLossPrice-200)
bracket[0].parentId = order.order.orderId # Set the parent ID for the main order

bracket[2].parentId = order.order.orderId # Set the parent ID for the stop loss order
bracket[2]. transmit = True # Set transmit to True for the stop loss order

bracket[1].parentId = order.order.orderId # Set the parent ID for the take profit order
bracket[1]. transmit = True # Set transmit to True for the take profit order

ib.placeOrder(contract, bracket) # Place the bracket order

ib.run()
ib.disconnect()
```

I get the error:

Error 201, reqId 1172: Order rejected - reason: Parent order is being cancelled.
Canceled order: Trade(contract=Future(symbol='ES', lastTradeDateOrContractMonth='202309', exchange='CME'),

I would appreciate your help to create the command so that I activate both stop loss and take profit at the same time and the first of them that is executed will cancel the corresponding operation.

Thanks in advance to all the helpers

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make the trade in several ways and every time I got Cancel
I also tried to read and apply the documentation but it was not clear enough

Comment: is this answer to your question?

Comment: I don't understand, I don't see the right link

Answer (score 0):

There a couple of things that do not work in the code:

1. ib.placeOrder returns a trade, not an order
2. More significant, it is explained in doc that you must have Transmit flag set to False for the parent and take profit orders and then setting the Transmit flag to True for the Stop order will send the whole bracket order.
   See https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/bracket_order.html

Answer (score 0):

#ib.placeOrder(contract, bracket)  # Place the bracket order
for order102 in bracket:
ib.placeOrder(contract, order102)
time.sleep(1)
I try this one,It is working, but only see main order be putted and need hand confirm, no other two brackets shows, I am working on it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).